# Apache Internal Sever Error after 5 minutes of waiting for a response using Dev Desktop on Win 10

Tags: apache, windows-10, drupal-8, php-7.2, acquia

I use xdebug with VS Code to inspect variables on my local Drupal 8 installation on Win 10, but after approximately 5 minutes (it is always the same amount of time) I get an Internal Server Error and can't inspect my variables any longer. I tried increasing memory_limit in my php.ini file but to no effect. I increased max_execution_time in php.ini and nothing changed. I increased FcgidIOTimeout and FcgidMaxRequestLen in httpd.conf and nothing changed. I got the following output from C:\Program Files (x86)\DevDesktop\apache\logs\error.log :

> [Sat May 25 12:37:02.785838 2019] [fcgid:warn] [pid 21796:tid 1112]
>   (OS 109)The pipe has been ended.  : [client 127.0.0.1:61083]
>   mod_fcgid: get overlap result error, referer:
>   http://drupal.dd:8083/node [Sat May 25 12:37:02.785838 2019]
>   [core:error] [pid 21796:tid 1112] [client 127.0.0.1:61083] End of
>   script output before headers: index.php, referer:
>   http://drupal.dd:8083/node

Please help.

Comment: Have you tried using the Apache module, within Dev Dektop config?

Comment: This may help: https://xdebug.org/archives/xdebug-general/2062.html